# Incremental SQL with label

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to extract from a single table in SQL Server 2008 R2... I have two columns.

```
IDate[Datetime] and ID[Numeric]
```

I am trying to build an MSSQL query that will return the following.

Searchable Criteria

```
 -IDate MM\DD\YYYY
 -ID ####
```

Returns

```
-HourIncrement 00:00 - 00:30
-RecordsForHour 3
-CumulativeRecords 3
-ID

-HourIncrement 00:30 - 01:00
-RecordsForHour 1
-CumulativeRecords 4
-ID
```

Sample data

[image]

Expected result

[image]

Comment: What's the part with which you are having difficulty?

Comment: So you would have 48 groups for every day? Assuming something happened in every increment?

Comment: Or do you need all 48, with sparse entries indicating RecordsForHour = 0 (and wouldn't RecordsForInterval be a better name....)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will provide the desired result, without using a CTE (common table expression), which may be easier to understand and may have better performance.

Defining the sample test data:

```
Declare  @test Table
(
     IDate      Datetime
    ,ID         Int
)

Insert Into @test(IDate,ID) Values
 ('2015-06-23 00:11:22.387',1000)
,('2015-06-23 00:15:52.192',1000)
,('2015-06-23 00:19:29.344',1000)
,('2015-06-23 00:39:20.660',1000)

,('2015-06-23 01:21:22.387',1000)
,('2015-06-23 01:25:52.192',1000)
,('2015-06-23 01:32:29.344',1000)
,('2015-06-23 01:39:20.660',1000)

,('2015-06-23 23:21:22.387',1000)
,('2015-06-23 23:25:52.192',1000)
,('2015-06-23 23:32:29.344',1000)
,('2015-06-23 23:39:20.660',1000)

,('2015-06-24 00:11:22.387',1000)
,('2015-06-24 00:15:52.192',1000)
,('2015-06-24 00:19:29.344',1000)
,('2015-06-24 00:39:20.660',1000)
```

The query:

```
select *
from
(
    select Convert(varchar, DayPeriod, 101) as DayPeriod,
    HourIncrement,
    count(*) as RecordForHour,
    max(rownum) as CumulativeRecords,
    min(ID) as ID
    from
    (
        select *, 
            Row_Number() over (order by IDate asc) as rownum,       
            DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, IDate)) as DayPeriod,
            case when DATEPART(mi, IDate) between 0 and 30
            then dateHour + ':00 - ' + dateHour + ':30'
            else dateHour + ':30 - ' + dateNextHour + ':00'
            end as HourIncrement
        from 
            (
                select *,
                right('00' + Convert(varchar(4), DATEPART(hh, IDate)), 2) as dateHour,
                right('00' + Convert(varchar(4), DATEPART(hh, DateAdd(hh, 1, IDate))), 2) as dateNextHour
                from @test
            ) t1
    ) t2
    group by DayPeriod, HourIncrement
) t3
order by CumulativeRecords asc
```

The result

[image]

Answer (score 0):

this could be helpful to you :-

```
Set Nocount On;

Declare @MinTime Time

Select   @MinTime = '00:00'

Declare  @test Table
(
     IDate      Datetime
    ,ID         Int
)

Declare @resultTable Table
(
     RowId              Int Identity(1,1) Primary Key
    ,RecordsPerHour     Int
    ,ID                 Int
    ,MinTime            Time
    ,MaxTime            Time
)

Insert Into @test(IDate,ID) Values
 ('2015-06-23 00:11:22.387',1000)
,('2015-06-23 00:15:52.192',1000)
,('2015-06-23 00:19:29.344',1000)
,('2015-06-23 00:39:20.660',1000)

;With timeCte As
(
    Select   @MinTime As minTime
            ,Dateadd(Mi, 30, @MinTime) As maxTime

    Union All

    Select   Dateadd(mi, 30, minTime) As minTime
            ,Case When t.maxTime = Cast('23:00' As Time) Then Dateadd(mi, 29, maxTime) Else Dateadd(mi, 30, maxTime) End As maxTime
    From    timeCte As t
    Where   t.maxTime < Cast('23:59' As Time)
)


Insert Into @resultTable(RecordsPerHour,ID,MinTime,MaxTime)
Select   Count(1) As RecordsForHour
        ,t.ID
        ,tc.minTime
        ,tc.maxTime
From    timeCte As tc With (Nolock)
        Join @test As t On Cast(t.IDate As Time) >= tc.minTime
            And Cast(t.IDate As Time) <= tc.maxTime
Group By t.ID
        ,tc.minTime
        ,tc.maxTime

Select   Cast(t.minTime As Varchar(5)) + ' - ' + Cast(t.maxTime As Varchar(5)) As Time
        ,t.RecordsPerHour
        ,t.RecordsPerHour + Isnull(t1.RecordsPerHour,0) As CumulativeRecords
        ,t.ID
From    @resultTable As t
        Left Join @resultTable As t1 On t.ID = t1.ID And t.RowId = (t1.RowId + 1)
Order By t.ID
        ,t.MinTime
        ,t.MaxTime
```

if you are using MSSQL Server 2012 or later then you can use Lag() function instead of left join to calculate CumulativeRecords.

**Output** of above query :-

[image]

Comment: Error, timeCte is not a defined system type

Comment: You may have copy-paste error, I have checked in MSSQL 2008 and 2012 as well, working without any issue. And CTE is always faster than any inner/sub-queries. And here, your question is also not clear to repeat the hours of whole day or only display time period occurrences in your data.

Comment: I would like to display all hours of the day even if 0 recs